# How to pass php variable to my script code and use document.write to display it?

Tags: javascript, php

This is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
    $php_var = "Hello world from PHP";
?>
<html style="margin-top:-8px; margin-left:-8px;">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pure-Convert</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calchome.css">
<script src="4func.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="converter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
      var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($php_var); ?>;
      document.write(js_var);
    </script>
</head>
<body >
<form action="cool.php" method="post">
<input name ="username" placeholder="Name">
<input name= "comment" placeholder="Make your mind heard..." />
<input type ="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically what I want to happen is I want $php_var to be converted to javascript. This what I have attempted. Can someone help me accomplish this?

```
<script>
          var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($php_var); ?>;
          document.write(js_var);
        </script>
```

Comment: The code you have will do what you describe. What's the problem?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: What do you mean by "converted to javascript" - do you need json_encode at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
  var js_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
  document.write(js_var);
</script>
```

Comment: The is the same as the existing code, but less robust. It will now break if the variable is a string with a `"` in it.

Comment: Have you tested both your PHP and JS to make sure they are working properly? Try an echo in php and assign js_var a value in JS to see if it displays

Comment: Oh, it will also break if the data include a new line or the sequence `</script>`.

Comment: A few questions: Are you inserting any special characters? And how are you doing the line break?

Comment: `json_encode` (which is used in the code in the question) will take care of any special characters and line breaks.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `document.write(js_var);`. What it does is writes that value to the DOM/HTML, possibly messing up everything (depends on the value).

```
<? php echo( '<script>var my_var=' . $my_value . ';</script>'); ?>

// In further js:
console.log( my_var );
```

Comment: This is less robust then the original script (it will break if the data include a `'` character) and no longer outputs the result to the document.

Comment: @Quentin: Question reads: "Basically what I want to happen is I want $php_var to be converted to javascript." And, furthermore, he's using `json_encode`, which allows us to guess the possible content of the value. About what "robustness" you are talking about? My solution registers that json as a global js variable, no `document.write` is needed.

Comment: `json_encode` already converts the data to the syntax of a JavaScript variable. Unlike your solution, it does proper escaping and can handle data types other than strings. Your answer is simple worse then the one already in the question.

Comment: It converts it to a VALUE, which can be used in js. What I'm doing is registering that value with an usable js identifier - var = value.

Comment: The code in the question — `var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($php_var); ?>;` — does that already (but more safely and more elegantly than yours).

Comment: No point in arguing. My code does the same (browser will get the same result). Main point was that he doesn't need `document.write`, since that will just write the value or his variable inside script tag, effectively breaking the javascript engine. Thanks for downvote.

Comment: It won't write the value inside the script tag, that would render `document.write` even more worthless then usual. `document.write` outputs the data immediately after the `</script>` tag (since the JavaScript doesn't get passed to the JS engine until the browser has parsed the entire script element and added it to the DOM).

Comment: No matter where it will write it. Raw, anonymous json data floating in the HTML doc is not a proper way of doing things.

Comment: That's very much a matter of opinion, and entirely irrelevant as far as *answers* to this question. It might be suitable as a comment.

Comment: I would like to see your answer, where you'd explain your thought in more detail. If ending up with an invalid HTML is a "matter of opinion", then I might be doing it wrong for many years.

Comment: There is nothing invalid about putting something that conforms to the JSON spec on the right hand side of an assignment in a script element (unless it includes `</script>` which it won't here because `json_encode` will output `<\/script>`). There is nothing invalid about using `document.write`. The only issue is that since the thing being written is body text, the script should be in the body instead of the head (but browsers will error recover from that). I'm not going to answer the question, because (as pointed out in my original comment on the question) there is no question to answer.

Comment: `json_encode` in php will fail on non-json-ish data (no script tags or whatever, stop your fantasy). This discussion would not take place if other encoding function were used in question, allowing for speculations that it could be a HTML string, thus valid candidate for `document.write`.

Comment: Dumping direct to a string will also fail on non-jsonish data. Passing an HTML string in a PHP variable through `json_encode` and echoing it will give you a JavaScript string literal (which is why `json_encode` is used for this sort of this).